# I'm not able to install lru_cache-0.2.3 in kali linux through terminal

Tags: python

I wanted to install lru_cache due to some import error in python so i downloaded the tar.gz file from here https://pypi.org/project/lru_cache/#files and i extracted the file and opened in terminal , like this  
 root@kali linux: ~/Downloads / **lru_cache-0.2.3**# 
 I did chmod +x * to allow all permissions to file inside the folder. 
 and then I wrote , 
INPUT 
 root@kali-linux:~/Downloads/lru_cache-0.2.3# python setup.py install 
 OUTPUT 
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lru_cache-0.2.3.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lru_cache-0.2.3.egg-info
 -------------------------------------------END----OF----CODE---------------------------------------
but the OUTPUT SHOULD BE THAT 
Installation of lru_chache Finished (something like that)

please help

Comment: Hello, what happens when you run `pip install lru_cache`?

Comment: Oh thanks for your reply but I solved it by putting python3 setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
Just put python3 instead of python in

 ** python setup.py install**